# org links inside source code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In my org file I have something like:

```
#+NAME: fig:figure
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{figure}
\end{figure}
```

and then I want to reference that figure inside a code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC r
    # code ...
    x <- 3
    # more code for fig. [[fig:figure]]
    plot(1:x)
#+END_SRC
```

[[fig:figure]] is not a link in the org document and does not get resolved when exported, it simply stays verbatim in the text. Is it somehow possible to make it reference the figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this. They key is the mathescape option for minted, and using minted for src block fontification.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq org-latex-minted-options
     '(("frame" "lines") ("linenos=true") ("mathescape")))
#+END_SRC



#+caption: figure for testing \label{fig-1}
[[./test.png]]

#+BEGIN_SRC ipython
5
# see figure $\ref{fig-1}$
4
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:results:
# Out [1]:
# text/plain
: 4
:end:
```

Comment: Is it right that this will only work for LaTeX export, i.e., no link-fontification in the org-buffer and the method does not work for other export targets?

Comment: that works, pretty cool! Is it possible to set the use of minted file local?

Comment: I think you can use org-latex-listings  to locally control which package is used. You want to set it to 'minted

Comment: Also this will only affect LaTeX exports. It won't fix anything in the org-buffer, or work for other export backends.

Comment: an even better way is the option `texcl`, it only works in comments but does not switch to the math font!